# how to show the loader dynamically until all the image load in jquery mobile phonegap listview

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, jquery-mobile, cordova

am having trouble to showing loader  untill all the image is load in the listview.the following code is used in my app.it  shows the loader untill all the image is load but the problem is , append the last src value to all the image attribute src.please help me.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.some.com/",
    type: 'POST',
    data: param,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (result) {
        $.each(result.results, function (k, v) {
            var searchPic = "http://www.some.com" + $.trim(v.eventIcon);
            var localarray = new Array();

            var c = v.eventText;
            strs = c.slice(0, 60);

            $('[data-role="listview"]').append('<li><a href="eventsview.html?id=' + v.nodeId + '&catname=' + v.eventTitle + '" data-ajax="false"> ' + '<img  alt="img" class="pic1"  src=" ">' + '<h4 >' + v.eventTitle + '</h4>' + '<p>' + strs + '...' + '</p></a></li>');
            $('[data-role="listview"]').listview('refresh');
            imgload(searchPic);
        });
        $('[data-role="listview"]').append('<li id="no-results">There is no record found based on your search criteria, please refine your search.</li>');

    }

});

function imgload(tx) {
    $('.pic1').load(function () {
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
    }).attr('src', tx);
}
});
```